# Angular 6: http get response

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, http, get

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to get a simple http get request and get this JSON: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users , specifically I want to loop the names only.

In the *app.module.ts* I added the HttpClientModule:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

In the *workers.component.ts*, this is what I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workers',
  templateUrl: './workers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workers.component.css']
})
export class WorkersComponent implements OnInit {
  showList = [];
  http: HttpClient;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //THIS IS WHAT I TRIED
    let obs = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    obs.subscribe(() => console.log('Got the response, yay.'));

    //Later I would try to get the name with response[0].name

  }

}
```

The *workers.component.html*, is very simple:

```
          <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr> 
                <td *nfFor="let name of names">{{name}}</td>    
              </tr>
            </tbody>         
      </table>
```

Currently, I just get the error:

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at WorkersComponent.push../src/app/workers/workers.component.ts.WorkersComponent.ngOnInit (workers.component.ts:29)*

Comment: `http` is not initialized

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? I added _http: HttpClient;_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject http inside the constructor do not declare as a variable type,

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-demo-get)**

Comment: This is what I get: https://ibb.co/cPRmTK
The error _Cannot read property 'get' of undefined_ again

Comment: Check the demo above

Answer (score 1):

import `HttpClientModule`

> app.module.ts

```
   imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ]
```

> workers.component.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Comment: I already did, forgot to mention it in the question. This is what it looks like: https://ibb.co/eNCzhe

Comment: if you are already import `HttpClientModule` then you are inject `private http: HttpClient` in your component constructor.

Comment: Yes! The **private** was the problem. I didn't said that in the component constructor. Thanks Krishna

Comment: What is different from the answer I posted above

Comment: Everyone has there own opinion . and I have imported `HttpClientModule` in app.module.ts

Comment: ya that's true, but i felt if there was anything different

Comment: Okay , but You are using deprecated `HttpModule` in `Stackblitz` URL

Comment: if you look it clearly, i added hte demo just for the demonstration and initially i saw you dint have the private

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178607/discussion-between-krishna-rathore-and-sajeetharan).